# Plotting ERA 5 Data for Specific Region on Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, boundaries, region

I am trying to plot (show data on interactive map) ERA 5 daily averaged  Precipitation, but I can't figure out how can I plot for a specific region (bounding box)? The map shows the data for the whole world, but I am interested in plotting data for a specific region.

Comment: When you say “plot”, do you mean you want to create a chart/graph, or do you only mean you want the interactive map to not show data outside of a certain region? Please [edit] your question to clarify this, and include the code you have so far.

Comment: Yes I want the interactive map to show data only for the region and not outside of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call [`ee.Image.clip`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-clip) on your image with the region. This will mask off all of the pixels not within the region.